Did Jesus know people thoughts because he was God or because he was a man who acquired that "power" through prayer?
I was reading the Mark's gospel second chapter where Jesus says "Son, your sins are forgiven" and Pharisees start to think that he is blaspheming. Then is written that Jesus knew what they were thinking. So, my question has two parts.

Was Jesus able to know their thoughts because he was God in human form as only God can know the hearts of the people or did he acquire that power as a human being through prayer and performing God's will?
If the second explanation is more apt, can we say that his disciples, Christians acquire that as well?
I ask this question because I have some friends who talk about some people who call themselves prophets and they seem to tell them what they have done in their past etc etc.
Thanks in advance.


Great question. This is something people have asked in one form or another for centuries - where is Jesus acting as a man would and where is Jesus acting as only God could. Be prepared for multiple points of view even from excellent Biblical scholars.

I think this question probably belongs on the Christianity site, as it seems mostly a theological question than an exegetical one. I'm hoping that answers here will at least focus on the Christology presented by Mark rather than giving a systematic explanation based on the whole NT.

This need not be an "either", "or" question. Both qualities were uniquely in the person of Jesus Christ.
First, the matter of a prophet telling another person what they have done in the past. The Bible does speak of God revealing matters to his prophets that could not possibly have been known by them. When Elisha's servant went behind Elisha's back to get monetary payment for a miracle Elisha had wrought, lying to Naaman, that servant knew God's judgment via Elisha. When he returned, having put the money and clothing in his house, he then lied to Elisha, saying he had not been anywhere. This is what Elisha said:

"Went not mine heart with thee, when the man turned again from his
chariot to meet thee? Is it a time to receive money, and to received
garments....? The leprosy therefore of Naaman shall cleave unto thee,
and unto thy seed for ever. And he went out from his presence a leper
as white as snow." 2 Kings 5:25-27 A.V.

God's prophet was told by the Spirit of God what greedy Gehazi had done, then prophesied what would happen not only next, but to all future generations of Gehazi. But Elisha was not God. Yet due to his faith, and faithfulness, God was pleased to empower that prophet in various ways (but not financially) - it must always be for God's glory.
With Jesus, there was a crucial difference, for he was God incarnate, as John 1:1-5 states. Yet his glory was hidden. He was far above other godly men, shown in how he taught, prophesied, and wrought miracles. There had been no prophet like him until then. He was greater than all who had gone before. Yes, he knew all about the Samaritan woman at Jacob's well, who had lived with seven men in turn, and the current man was not her husband. She did not tell him that. She only answered, honestly, "I have no husband." But when Jesus showed he knew all about her, the result was returning to the village to tell the men to come and see this Jesus who "told me all things that ever I did: is not this the Christ?" (John 4:2-29) The result was the conversion of many Samaritan people as Jesus stayed with them 2 days, and even more people believed. And Jesus gave prophecies about the future.
Jesus humbled himself to become a human, but he never gave up his deity (Colossians 2:15-19). The disciples knew they had seen his glory, John 1:14-18 and the transfiguration. But if Jesus, as man, had thought to set out in his own strength and wisdom and power, he would not have had the Spirit's enabling. Daily, he sought to know the Father's will, and to do it. He saw Nathaniel sitting under a fig tree before ever Philip approached him to lead him to Jesus. He knew Nathaniel's heart was good - "an Israelite in whom there is no guile", but Psalm 44:21 says it is God who searches out and knows the secrets of the heart (& Psalm 139:1-13). Both revelations caused Nathaniel to acclaim Jesus as the Son of God (John 1:45-51). Jesus accepted such acclamation (also Thomas calling him his Lord and his God) for he was God incarnate. Those whom the Spirit revealed such things to, followed Jesus as their Lord and their God.
Above all else, Jesus' authority to forgive sins, while on Earth, proved he was truly the Son of God, which equated him with God, as even his enemies acknowledged:

"But there were certain of the scribes sitting there and reasoning in
their hearts, Why doth this man thus speak blasphemies? Who can
forgive sins but God only? And immediately when Jesus perceived in
his spirit that they so reasoned within themselves, he said unto them,
Why reason ye these things in your heart?" Mark 2:5-9 A.V.
[emphasis mine]

Prayer is certainly powerful, but the minute any person thinks they can pray their way into obtaining special gifts, their deficiency of heart will betray them to God. False prophets abound, and they may claim to do and say things miraculously, setting themselves up for adulation (and financial gain). Their fall will be great. Humble believers in Jesus know what the indwelling Holy Spirit truly does in them, and all for God's glory.
"Acquiring power" was attempted by one called Simon the sorcerer, but the apostles warned him to repent of such wickedness. Read all about that in Acts 8:9-24, to see the difference between the genuine gifting via the Holy Spirit that the apostles had, and sinful attempts to be seen as having supernatural power. Neither did Jesus "acquire power through prayer". He has power because of who he is - and while on Earth, that was, God incarnate.

Jesus … for he was God incarnate, as John 1:1-5 states. Please confirm the validity of this statement. Does it mention Jesus, or incarnation for that matter? This is BH not SE.C.

@Steve It also makes little sense to question the premise of the question in this way, or every Trinitarian-premised question would become a debate about the theology. Naturally the question is very easy to resolve if you don't approach it from that premise. But the question is not about that argument.

In that case the site’s name is an empty euphemism. Either we uphold such principles or we post on Christianity. Here it’s about the Bible and hermeneutical process, not random dogma as anyone might cobble together from anywhere!

@Steve There are numerous passages which state Jesus is God in the same way the Father is God and the Spirit is God. Even if you look only at the original text of the Prologue the question is the difference between the theos and theos. It is absurd to assume the reader would see the matter settled in verse 1. Rather verse 1 raises the question "what type of theos?" Which the Prologue immediately answers, one that created all things, is the true light, is the light of life, etc. After the Prologue, the Gospel "piles" on to show He is equal with the Father.

@Anne I notice your comment and wonder why you didn't follow your own sound principles. "What does the text say, or what does it not say?"
Sep 14, 2023 at 13:50 The matter of Jesus' deity as noted has nothing to do with the text. Perhaps on Christianity, this might be acceptable where the Bible is often irrelevant. Awaiting your explanation of validity of this claim according to BH standards.

Hi everyone, thank you very much for the responses. I wanted to understand for myself what the meaning of the context was and how it relates to myself. I am no expert in biblical text but a person who is interested in learning the truth.

I have never read this passage as implying a supernatural ability to read thoughts:  Jesus is just "reading the room."  He knew that only God can forgive sins, that to suggest otherwise was blasphemy, and that the scholars there also knew this.  Their thoughts are explained for the benefit of the Gentile reader of the scripture, who would otherwise miss important context.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The answer to this question is implied in John's conclusion to his gospel:

John 14:12 - “Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever believes in me will
also do the works that I do; and greater works than these will he do,
because I am going to the Father.

That is, Jesus used no power that He will not make available to His disciples.
Now, we are not told how Jesus acquired the knowledge of anyone's thoughts (information available only to God); however, the most likely explanation is that Jesus was inspired by the Holy Spirit to know and do things - the same Holy Spirit imparted to the disciples by Jesus as recorded in John 20:22 and Acts 1 & 2, etc.
